# How many ways are there for them to create a display?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to find the answer to this two part problem but I can't seem to get it right

### Problem

A farm stand wants to create a display with 20 pieces of fruits or vegetables.  Assuming that they have 16 different kinds of produce and a large amount available of each type, how many ways are there for them to create a display? How would your answer change if you want at least 3 pumpkins included in the display?

### My thinking

For each of the 20 spots on the display, the item can be one of 16 different types of fruits or vegetables.

![(16+20-1)!/20!(16-1)!=3,247,943,160]
(https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft(16%2B20%2B1%5Cright)!%7D%7B20!%5Cleft(16-1%5Cright)!%7D%3D3%2C%20247%2C%20943%2C%20160)

If you wanted at least 3 pumpkins in the display, at least 3 spots on the display could only contain pumpkins while the rest could contain any of the 16 fruits or vegetables

![(16+20-1)!/20!(16-1)!3!=541,323,860]
(https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft(16%2B20%2B1%5Cright)!%7D%7B20!%5Cleft(16-1%5Cright)!3!%7D%3D541%2C323%2C860)

My question is where did I go wrong and what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Your answer assumes the order of fruits and vegetables does not matter.  If the order matters, the answer to the first question is simply $16^{20}$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig My professor said order does not matter in this situation. That's why I am confused on what I did wrong. Did I calculate the answer incorrectly?

Comment: Your answer to the first question looks right.  For the second question, place three pumpkins in the display.  Then you have to select $17$ additional fruits of vegetables from $16$ types of vegetables.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig That makes sense. Thank you!